# how can I get around the 0x80030001 error when trying to copy files from a set of search results in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, android

I'd like to search for mp3 files in a subfolder on my Android phone and copy them to my computer so I can listen to them. These are podcasts. When I use Windows Explorer to do this I get this error when I try to copy them:

`0x80030001 unable to perform requested operation`

I've tried using [CubicExplorer](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-replacements-for-windows-explorer/?tag=content%3Bblog-list-river) but it doesn't seem to be able to search the phone's files. Is there any way around this bug? It seems like MS is not going to fix it based on what I've read.

The only work around is to search, then open file location one by one, then copy one by one. Pretty lame.

I would just play these files directly from VLC but that won't work, VLC errors out when I try that. I reported it as a bug and they said it wasn't, essentially.

Comment: Error you are getting during the copy of mp3 files from android phone to my computer is that the drive format would be fat32.We request you to type msconfig.exe  in the search windows. Now windows open,click on the service and then Tick the Hide all Microsoft services. Choose Disable all. Now Choose Startup and  Choose disable all. once it is done please do a system boot and then check whether you are able to transfer the file

Comment: @vembutech I gotta say, that doesn't make any sense. You want me to disable all my non MS services? Then reboot? Have you actually solved my problem this way? Because it sounds like you are guessing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is you try to move the files from "search results".  If you can locate where is the file (e.g. using "Open file location" from context menu) you can copy/move the files.  [Reference](http://www.askmefast.com/Error_0x80030001_copying_music_files_from_phone_to_computer-qna3805059.html#q4375553)

Answer (score 1):

Connect your android phone with your PC as USB storage. To connect your mobile as USB storage go to `Settings -> more settings -> USB utilities -> Connect storage to PC`

Note: The path will be vary depends on the android OS.

Now search the files and you can copy the files to your compute and play it or you can play it directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect iphone6 to PC
2. Using Windows Explorer, Open phone folder
3. Search for *.mov
4. Select latest file
5. Right click it and "open file location".
6. Copy to PC.

Comment: -1, tagged as android