# Transferring multiple mp3 files after search function

Tags: windows-7, mp3

I have recently bought a small mp3 player for swimming and wish to transfer multiple files from my existing normal mp3 player. Up until today, I never realised I could do a search within sub folders and I had been going to each location and selecting various files one at a time and transferring (laborious process!)

So, after discovering the search *.mp3 function, eureka, all my mp3 files from my player were displayed. Great I thought, so I selected about 20 files to copy over to new location but it won't do it! I tried copying to a folder on my desktop, but I kept getting an

> Unexpected error 0x800300001

I can copy/drag one file at a time still and this transfers OK, but it is not much better than what I was originally doing.

Is there any way to get all my mp3 files listed, select the ones I want to transfer, and then copy/drag to new file location?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks for question, but , <br/> this is already answered: [0x80030001-error](http://superuser.com/questions/847700/how-can-i-get-around-the-0x80030001-error-when-trying-to-copy-files-from-a-set-o)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you try to move the files from "search results". If you can locate where is the file (e.g. using "Open file location" from context menu) you can copy/move the files. Reference